# webpack pack the unimport modules , is it design like that?

Tags: javascript, webpack

why webpack pack the unuse value to the output file?

**// ------    common.js  ----**

```
const a=3;
const b=4;
export {a,b}
```

//--------------------------

**//------------  index.js--------**

```
import {a} from "common"
console.log(a)
```

after the webpack process ;

the output file still include the const b=4;

**how can i pack the source just include the import module?**

Comment: Are you running webpack in Production mode?

Comment: yes , i  running webpack in Production mode by setting the webpack.config.js mode:"production "

Answer (score 0):

use

```js
export const a = 3; 
export const b = 4;
```

instead of

```js
const a=3;
const b=4;
export {a,b}
```